# how to create gridview in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-viewpager

i want to make image detail gallery with gridview,  i have slidingTablayout with 2num, and i dont know how to place gridview in viepager on 2 fragment that i have

here is my code

History_proyek.java

```
public class History_proyek extends AppCompatActivity {

TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void  onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_history);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getApplicationContext()));

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        });
    }


private class CustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    private String fragments [] = {"Proyek Selesai","Proyek dalam Proses"};
    public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager,Context applicationContext){
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new Fragment1();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment2();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.length;
    }
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return fragments[position];

    }
}}
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_history1, container,false);
}}
```

Fragment2.java

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_history2, container, false);
}}
```

layout_history.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#4f4f4f"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    />

</LinearLayout>
```

frag_history1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_view1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

</GridView>
```

frag_history2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_view2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

</GridView>
```